# flexslider arrows not aligning on mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am developing a mobile version of my website using the Flexslider, which is useful because of its fluid properties.  However, if you look at it on a mobile browser the arrors are misaligned and the rest of the areas of the site are hiding behind the images in some way.  It may be do to some positioning of some sort but I do most of my debugging on my regular browsers and just change the user agent to show me my mobile application version.

If you go to the site from a User Agent changed browser on your computer it will look like this (which is how I want it to look):

[image]

If I you look at the site on the phone devsuper.artistcon.com you will see that the arrows are missaligned and the elements of the collapsable goes under the images:

[image]

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if your css property has the following

```
.flexslider {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    margin: 0 0 60px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
}

.flex-direction-nav a {
display: block;
height: 40px;
margin: -20px 0 0;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
z-index: 10;
}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
opacity: 1;
right: 10px;
}
```

I assume you don't have **top: 50%;** property in your **.flex-direction-nav a** rule